# Cannot find the pin numbering of Micro D Sub Connector

Tags: connector

Here is the 9 pin [connector](http://www.newark.com/itt-cannon/mdm-9ph003b/micro-d-connector-plug-9pos-crimp/dp/90B4801) I need to solder by using a diagram. But for that I need to find the pin numbering of this connector. In datasheet it is not given.

Are the pins of this connector numbered the same way as a classic DB-9 connector as this: https://www.db9-pinout.com/?

I couldn't find any info in net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are usually tiny pin numbers on either side of the connector. In your case these might be on the side where the wires are connected. Or you can look for an alternative datasheet source, such as [this one](http://download.siliconexpert.com/pdfs/2012/11/27/3/10/7/565/itt_/manual/mdm.pdf), having the following picture on page 9:
[image]